# Android activities launch behavior

Tags: android, android-activity

My app has two activities. Activity `A` is the main activity and it has

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

in the manifest. I do not set any `android:launchMode` for `A`. Activity `A` launches Activity `B`. I press home button in activity `B` and return to Android menu. If I press my app icon in Android menu, would it launch new instance of activity `A` or return back to `B`?

I can see it returns back to activity `B` and I do not understand why. As I did not set `android:launchMode`, it should launch new instance of `A` every time I press icon, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activity B launches because when you press your `Home` button, the application is not "closed", but merely sent to the background. Such is the workflow of Android. If you want to finish Activity B when it is sent to the background, you can call `this.finish()` in an overridden `onPause()` function in Activity B.

For more information on managing the Activity lifecycle, check out this very useful tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html